# Decrypt RSA based encryption using Apache NiFi

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg, pycrypto, apache-nifi

I am using a python script that uses pycrypto to encrypt files using RSA. I have used `encrypt(data, 2048)` function during encryption.

Now, I am trying to decrypt that encrypted file using the decrypt processor in Apache NiFi and I am not sure which `KDF` and `Encryption Algorithm` to select.

I do not see anything termed `RSA` in the `Configure Processor` window of Apache NiFi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the `EncryptContent` processor does not support arbitrary RSA decryption. I would suggest you [file a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) requesting this enhancement (don't be scared by the graph showing a discrepancy between opened & closed; we're currently at the phase of the lifecycle where a release went out recently and now all the feedback is generating new tickets for the next release).

For immediate solutions, I have a few suggestions:

- You can use GPG to encrypt and decrypt the data, and NiFi provides first-class support for GPG decryption. The GPG key uses an underlying DSA/RSA key alongside AES encryption for the data, so this would be effectively the same process (asymmetric encryption).
- You can use the [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor to run a small script which performs the decryption. The processor supports Ruby, Groovy, Lua, Javascript, and Python*. Unfortunately the limitation on Python is that Jython doesn't support native libraries (such as pycrypto). One possible solution is to use [JyNI](https://github.com/Stewori/JyNI) which allows Jython to load CPython libraries, but I have not evaluated it in this context. If you are comfortable with Groovy & BouncyCastle or Ruby & OpenSSL, you can write the decrypt script in either of those languages with only a few lines of code.
- If you really want to use the Python code you already have, you can invoke it on the command-line via [`ExecuteProcess`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) or [`ExecuteStreamCommand`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html).

One outstanding question -- how are you using RSA to encrypt the files? RSA with a 2048 bit key length can only encrypt 245 bytes. If you are encrypting files, it is more likely you would want to use a hybrid cryptosystem, where you encrypt the arbitrary data with a randomly-generated AES key and then encrypt just that AES key with RSA. This will be much faster as well. This is the model used by SSL, S/MIME, OpenPGP, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions. I am actually using AES_CBC with SHA256 to encrypt my data symmetrically. My python script is then encrypting that symmetric key using `pycrypto's` RSA. So with the GPG encryption, will it automatically encrypt underlying data with AES and also use PKI on the outside?

Comment: Yes, GPG will encapsulate AES encryption of the data, sign the cipher text with the sender's private key, and encrypt the AES key with the recipient(s)' public key. It appears there is a Python library for [python-gnupg](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg) which can make this easier for you on the sending end.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a tutorial on how to decrypt it using nifi given that I am able to use python-gnupg to generate an encrypted file?

Comment: I don't have a good tutorial -- it's pretty straightforward. Set the mode to decrypt, the algorithm to `PGP`/`PGP_ASCII_ARMOR` depending on if you Base64 encoded the output, and populate the PGP private keyring file location and the passphrase.